# Finding the Index of an Item that was already Deleted

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, observablelist

I have an original `ObservableList<PlanItem> src`.

I create a SortedList from this `src`, and call it `sortedList`.

From the `sortedList`, I want to create an `ObservableList<XYChart.Data>`, called `dataSet`. `sortedList` and `dataSet` will always be of the same size. `sortedList` has `PlanItems`, `dataSet` has `XYChart.Data` nodes representative of those `PlanItems`.

If a `PlanItem` is deleted from the `src`, the `sortedList` will also delete it. At the same time, I want to delete its respective `XYChart.Data` node from the `dataSet`.

The problem is, I don't know what was just deleted from the `sortedList`. I can't find a way to determine the index that was just deleted. Without knowing this index, I have no way of deleting the respective `XYChart.Data` node from the `dataSet`.

Comment: How are you deleting the item from sortedList? Can't you delete both at the same time?

Comment: The items are deleted from the original list. This fires a notification to the SortedList to also delete it at the same time. Unfortunately, I have to manually find a way to "fire a notification" to the dataSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really nice use case for the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework. You can just create a mapping from `sortedList` to `dataSet` and it will handle all the additions and deletions for you.

The code would look something like

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data> dataSet = EasyBind.map(sortedList, this::makeChartData) ;

// ...

private XYChart.Data makeChartData(PlanItem planItem) {
    // Just return a XYChart.Data corresponding to planItem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I could really use it.